# I want my android app to send an email automatically without an intent (Kotlin!)

Tags: android, kotlin, email

Hello I want to send an email from my android app without using intent, startActivity etc. Is there any way to do it? I can hardly find any piece of codes in kotlin and everywhere they use intent. I only found this: https://github.com/1902shubh/SendMail. If I try to implement this solution in the following way:

**root level gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.3.0'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.1902shubh:SendMail:1.0.0'
    ...
}
```

**my kotlin code**

```
val mail = SendMail(
        "youremail@email.com", "yourEmailsPass",
        "otherUser'sEmail@email.com",
        "Title",
        "Yes, it's working well\nI will use it always.:)"
         )
mail.execute()
```

it says *Unresolved reference: SendMail* and does't want to implement anyting. Could anyone tel me what is the problem?

Comment: Regarding your technical problem, did you add an `import` for the fully-qualified class name of this `SendMail` class? Beyond that, please understand that putting your email credentials into an app means that your email account will be harvested by others and used to send spam.

Comment: ok. So what is the better solution? I want to make app which send a verification code to email given in the registration form, what should I do?

Comment: Regarding email credentials I will try to set up another Account for the very app

Comment: "So what is the better solution?" -- either launch the user's preferred email app, or find some solution that does not involve sending an email. "I will try to set up another Account for the very app" -- that does not change the security issues around your approach. You may wish to discuss your plans with your attorney.

Comment: I think many apps work like this. If you register in an app you always get a verification code from particular email(assigned to this particular app). I don't get your point of view, what security issues do you mean? I don't wan't to discuss my plans with attorney, first of all, I want to make the working app. The next or even last step is distributing this app...

Comment: "If you register in an app you always get a verification code from particular email(assigned to this particular app)" -- yes, but they send their email from their own secure Web service. They do not send the email from the app itself. "what security issues do you mean?" -- I mean that your email credentials baked into the app will be stolen and used to deliver spam. phishing attacks, and so on.

Comment: ok thanks for your response. I will try to gain some information about web services